# How to save Image path in database

Tags: java, database, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am working on web application in which user can upload a image say at(D:\media). I have added in **host** param of my **server.xml** of tomcat

```html
<Context docBase="D:\media" path="/media" />
```

So now every Image at"D:\media" can be viewed at "localhost:8080/media" as(take example of abc.png)

```
localhost:8080/media/abc.png
```

I am just showing image in jsp when required as

```html
<img src="localhost:8080/media/abc.png">
```

my question is how and which imagepath to store in database when user uploads image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the image right to the database from the servlet that process the post request. You must use this attribute in the form: enctype='multipart/form-data' and then get the Part with its parameter name like this:

```
//request in the HttpServletRequest.
Part uploadedFile = request.getPart("parameterName");
InputStream is = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
byte[] fileData = new byte[add a preferred size];
is.read(fileData);
//Save fileData in the database.
```

Here you can have more info with examples: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.servlet.http.Part